# How to create a method with an empty parameter list in java

Tags: java, methods, linked-list

I'm having a brain fart and for some reason I can't figure out how to write a method where the parameters are empty.

I have a method here (empty)

```
public void removeRepeat() {
}
```

This is for a linked list and I want to remove repeats. I have other methods below that I'm thinking of using to go about it:

```
public boolean remove(Object element) {
        Node<T> current = head;
        if(isEmpty()) {
            return false;
        }
        if(current.getValue() == element){
            head = head.getNext();
            size--;
            return true;
        }
        while(current.getNext().getValue() != element) {
            current = current.getNext();
            if(current == null) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        if(current.getNext().getNext() == null) {
            tail = current;
        }
        current.setNext(current.getNext().getNext());
        size--;
        return true;
    }
```

I also have a set method and whatnot, but my question is generally how to write the method if there are no parameters. Do I just create a new variable? How do I access the list it wants me to reverse? I'm thinking to have a for loop to check for repeats and then remove the repeating element, but I'm not sure how to construct the for loop.
`for (int i=0; i< ???; i++)`

Comment: You can access all instance variables from your method

Answer (score 1):

Broadly speaking there four major ways you can access a variable inside a method in Java:

- Provide the variable as parameter:

```
public void removeRepeat(SomeObject obj)
{
    // do something with obj
}
```

- Have the variable be a member (seems like this is true for `head` in your second code snippet):

```
SomeObject obj = new SomeObject();

public void removeRepeat()
{
    // do something with obj
}
```

- Declare the variable locally, *i.e.* inside the method:

```
public void removeRepeat()
{
    SomeObject obj = new SomeObject();
    // do something with obj
}
```

- Have it be available statically somewhere:

```
// some other class
public class SomeClass
{
    public static final Object obj = new SomeObject();
}

...

// then in your class:

public void removeRepeat()
{
    SomeObject obj = SomeClass.obj;
    // do something with obj
}
```

I recommend getting over some Java basics, it should clear up some misconceptions you might have about this.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by your `remove(Object element)` method, you have a class that contains a `head` and a `tail` field, as well as a `size` field.

If you are adding a new method `removeRepeat()` to the same class, then you can go ahead and access these fields just like in the `remove(Object)` method.
For example,

```
public void removeRepeat() {
    // Make a method-local copy of the class's "head" field.
    Node<T> current = head;
    // Iterate through the list here:
    while (current != null) {
        // do something
        current = current.getNext();
    }
    etc...
 }
```